# Alternative to ReliableSqlConnection for async Azure SQL calls

Tags: c#, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database, enterprise-library

We are currently using ReliableSqlConnection for all calls to our Azure SQL database. This works fine.
But unfortunately the Enterprise Library is from 2013 and it seems not to be developed anymore. But the main issue is, that **async** db calls are not supported.

I've been searching SO and other places, but the only thing I could find so far was Polly. And even [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) does not seem to be widely used and I have not found an example for SQL Server.
I know that ADO.NET supports retry for SqlConnection.Open(), but not for commands, so it's not a real solution. I'm a bit surprised that we seem to be the only ones having this problem?

Comment: Did you take a look at the build-in support: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456835(v=vs.113).aspx? Seems like the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` is a good fit for your scenario. We use this and it works fine.

Comment: Ok, this sounds interesting. Do you have more information on how you use this exactly? Especially for "normal" SqlConnection DB calls (Not the entity framework).

Comment: Not sure if that can be DB related, but have you thought about using Dapper? http://dapper-tutorial.net/async and https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Answer (score 3):

Little known fact, transient fault tolerance is now built into the connection string (.NET 4.6.1+). [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-issues) says:

> If your client program connects to to Azure SQL Database by using the .NET Framework class `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, **you should use .NET 4.6.1 or later (or .NET Core) so you can leverage its connection retry feature.** [Details of the feature are here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632678.aspx).
>
> When you build the connection string for your `SqlConnection` object, you should coordinate the values among the following parameters:
>
> `ConnectRetryCount`   (Default is 1. Range is 0 through 255.)
>     `ConnectRetryInterval`   (Default is 1 second. Range is 1 through 60.)
>     `Connection Timeout`   (Default is 15 seconds. Range is 0 through 2147483647)
>
> Specifically, your chosen values should make the following equality true:
>
> ```
> Connection Timeout = ConnectRetryCount * ConnectionRetryInterval
> ```
>
> For example, if the count = 3, and interval = 10 seconds, a timeout of only 29 seconds would not quite give the system enough time for its 3rd and final retry at connecting: 29 < 3 * 10.

Comment: Yes, we had a look at this. But this only covers the connection. But not if something fails during the command, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what "Transport only" means?  Is something like cmd.ExecuteReader() covered or not really?

Comment: I would assume it recovers if ExecuteReader() is trying to grab a connection that no longer sits on a good TCP channel underneath. But higher up in the protocol.. don't know, i would open a support case with Azure SQL to get these details, the documentation around this new connection retry feature is a little thin.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a pretty good example of Polly usage in eShopOnContainers project (A demo on how to develop microservices architectures...)

Well, the are using a Circuit Breaker implementation,  ( take a look here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Web/WebMVC/Infrastructure )  ,I'd say that in the same way they do the HTTP connections for consuming rests you could do the same with your async SQL connections...

The are using it like:

```
 if (Configuration.GetValue<string>("UseResilientHttp") == bool.TrueString)
  {
      services.AddSingleton<IResilientHttpClientFactory, ResilientHttpClientFactory>();
      services.AddSingleton<IHttpClient, ResilientHttpClient>(sp => sp.GetService<IResilientHttpClientFactory>().CreateResilientHttpClient());
  }
  else
  {
      services.AddSingleton<IHttpClient, StandardHttpClient>();
  }
```

So you might be able to create you ResilientSqlClient and use it in a similar way.

I hope it helps you to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Async and Await patterns as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming)?

Hope this helps.

Comment: The patterns are fine. Thanks. But they don't really cover the transient error situation that we might encounter on Azure SQL. Or did I miss something.